# What did Joel Spolsky mean in the paradox of a variable's value not changing and changing at the same time?

Tags: recursion, scheme, purely-functional

I read [The perils of Java Schools](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html) about 8 months ago and since then I have been using it as a check list for the things I should learn soon. I understand most of what he is speaking about.

There's however this part that I am not quite sure about:

> in a purely functional program, the value of a variable never changes, and yet, it changes all the time! A paradox!

What I'm getting from this(forgive me if I'm wrong) is that he's talking about recursion but recursion seems
 too simple a concept. Here's my line of thought:

```
(define (tail-rec n) 
  (if (= n 1) 
    (display "Done!") 
    (begin 
       (display n)
       (newline) 
       (tail-rec (- n 1)))))
```

The value of `n` in the tail recursive function `tail-rec` does not change yet when you look at what is being output, you see that it actually changes. Also since the function itself is not changing the state
of any variable, it means that it is purely functional.
Soo... 
**Am I right about this?** 
**Is this what Joel was talking about?** If not, please correct me.

Comment: Ah! Come on, two downvotes already? I'm not trying to be subjective here. I just want an answer. I'll remove the references to the Java School student if it's going to lead to me getting an answer.

Comment: In this case n isn't so much a variable per se, it's a formal parameter of a function and is bound in it's own scope. Each call has it's own different N, but this n is never changed. The is when you unwind this call each n has its own value that is never changed, but it may not be the same value as some other n. Whereas jave you would usually do this as a for loop with i=0, i<0n i-- where we use the same I at different states in the program.

Comment: The reason you got the minus I suspect is because your example is not purely functional.  Yes pure functions don't use assignment, but they also don't create side effects, or have a concept of state or order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, Joel's article was indeed referring to recursion in that context.

However, your code isn't actually pure-functional, because `display` and `newline` have side effects. So I'm going to go off on a tangent and give you some tangible examples of pure-functional recursive code.

Consider a [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) function:

```
(define (gcd x y)
  (if (zero? y)
      x
      (gcd y (modulo x y))))
```

Here, each time where the remainder of dividing `x` by `y` is non-zero, it (tail-)recursively calls `gcd` again, where in this new call, the `x` and `y` values are different. (In particular, the `y` value gets smaller each iteration, eventually leading to a base case where `x` divides `y` exactly, even if `y` has to be 1 in order for that to happen.)

Here's another case of pure-functional recursion (not tail recursion, this time, though [it's possible to implement with tail recursion](http://dyscour.se/post/58639636506/named-let) too), used to implement an algorithm for merging two sorted lists of numbers:

```
(define (merge lhs rhs)
  (cond ((null? lhs) rhs)
        ((null? rhs) lhs)
        ((< (car rhs) (car lhs))
         (cons (car rhs) (merge lhs (cdr rhs))))
        (else
         (cons (car lhs) (merge (cdr lhs) rhs)))))
```

Again, whenever we're dealing with cases where both `lhs` and `rhs` are non-empty, we recurse into another call into `merge`, with one of the lists being shorter in each call, and we eventually get to a base case where one of the lists is empty.

This merge function can be used to implement mergesort:

```
(define (mergesort lst)
  (let ((len (length lst)))
    (if (< len 2)
        lst
        (let-values (((lhs rhs) (split-at lst (quotient len 2))))
          (merge (mergesort lhs) (mergesort rhs))))))
```

This is the classic example of a [divide-and-conquer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm). Each time the list has 2 or more elements, split the list into left and right halves, recurse into each half, then merge the sorted halves back together.

Comment: Isn't begin also non-functional, as it relies of the concept of time and order, rather than on evaluation or functions.

Comment: `begin` is a "pure functional code smell", in that it's seldom used outside of side-effecting contexts, but by itself it's not inherently side-effecting.

Comment: I've never understood how a `print` or `display` function is not purely functional. What state is being changed by these functions? The input/output buffer?

Comment: @Segfault, any IO is a side effect whether it's printing to a terminal or interacting with a database. A pure function's only interaction with the rest of the world are via its parameters and return value.